# I've 2 LWC comp where I'm navigating from 1 page to 2nd pg in community which have list of rec which can be filtered acc to provided list of statuses

Tags: lightning-web-components, lightning-community, lwc-wire-adapter, community-builder

I have 2 LWC components in 1st component I am showing count of records based on different status values and whenever I am clicking on those number of counts, I am navigating to 2nd page of community which consists of 2nd LWC component. 2nd component showing list of records which is also having a status filter according to which we can filter the list of records.

Now, my requirement is to navigate from 1st page to 2nd page & status filter should be automatically applied.
Suppose, If I am clicking on 1st number which is calculated based on status 1 then I should navigate to 2nd page and status filter should have that status 1 value and list should be sorted accordingly as well. Please enlighten how to do this.
My guess is If I can use state in navigation mixin handler of 1st component somehow and in 2nd component using current page reference. However, unable to achieve this, also the console I am applying in navigation mixin are not giving any useful values.

Please find the code for reference.

1st Component HTML -

```
<template if:true={bool}>
        <div class="slds-grid slds-grid_vertical">
            <c-generic-container title= {label.AllTasks} description= {label.AllTasksHomeDescription}>
                <div class="slds-col slds-p-around_x-small"
                     slot="genericBodySection">
                     <div class="slds-grid slds-grid_align-left">
                        <div class="slds-col slds-var-m-vertical_xx-small slds-size_1-of-3 task-header flex-grow task-container-1" style="text-align:left">
                            {label.OpenTasks}
                            <div class="slds-col slds-var-m-vertical_xx-small open-task-count flex-grow " style="text-align:left" >
                                <a href="" onclick={handlerClick}>
                                {countedOpenTasks}
                                </a>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div>
                            <div class="path-icon-separator-1"></div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="slds-col slds-var-m-vertical_xx-small slds-size_1-of-3 task-header flex-grow task-container-2" style="text-align:left">
                            {label.OverdueTasks}
                            <div class="slds-col slds-var-m-vertical_xx-small overdue-task-count flex-grow" style="text-align:left" onclick={handlerClick}>
                                <a href="" onclick={handlerClick}>
                                {countedOverdueTasks}
                                </a>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div>
                            <div class="path-icon-separator-2"></div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="slds-col slds-var-m-vertical_xx-small slds-size_1-of-3 task-header flex-grow task-container-3" style="text-align:left">
                            {label.UnassignedTasks}
                            <div class="slds-col slds-var-m-vertical_xx-small unassigned-task-count flex-grow" style="text-align:left" onclick={handlerClick}>
                                <a href="" onclick={handlerClick}>
                            {countedUnassignedTasks}
                            </a>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
    
                </div>
                
            </c-generic-container>
        </div>

    </template>
```

1st component JS -

```
//handler for navigating to community page consisting of list view 
handlerClick(event){
this.clickTaskData = event.target.text;
this.stringData = event.target;
this.showit= event.detail.countedOpenTasks;
console.log('this.clickTaskData '+this.clickTaskData);
console.log('this.stringData '+this.stringData);
console.log('this.showit '+this.showit);
this[NavigationMixin.Navigate]({
    type: 'comm__namedPage',
    attributes: {
        name: 'TaskList__c'
    },
    state:'Status',
});
}
```

2nd component HTML

```
<template if:true={enableDatatable}>
    <c-generic-list-view direct-column-property-input={columns} records-per-page={recordsPerPage}
    records={myTaskWrappers} table-name={labels.allTasks} 
    search-bar-text={labels.findTaskSearchBar} searchable-cols={searchableColsList}
    column-is-sortable-default=true hide-column-default-actions-default=true
    display-row-selector=true onrowsselected={getSelectedRow} max-row-selection=1 >
    </c-generic-list-view>
</template>
```

2nd Component JS-

```
listViewRecordsString = JSON.stringify([
    {label: anyStatus, value: anyStatus,selected:true},
    {label: notStarted, value: notStarted,selected:false},
    {label: pendingReassignment, value: pendingReassignment,selected:false},
    {label: inProgress, value: inProgress,selected:false},
    {label: unassigned, value: unassigned,selected:false},
    {label: completed, value: completed,selected:false},
    // {label: ignored, value: ignored,selected:false}
]);

handleStatusFilter(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    let statusVal = event.detail.value;
    if (statusVal === anyStatus) {
        this.myTaskWrappers = this.tableQuery;
    }
    else {
        let tmpList = [];
        for(let i=0; i< this.tableQuery.length;i++) {
            if (this.tableQuery[i].Status__c === statusVal ) {
                tmpList.push(this.tableQuery[i]);
            }
        }
        this.myTaskWrappers = tmpList;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're onto the right idea by using the State property, but you need to update the way that you're defining this. The State attribute of the PageReference used in the navigation is an object consisting of key value pairs, so you need to not only define the state you want to have passed, but also the value of this state.

To begin with, you also need to be able to identify which of the sections has actually been clicked on. You can do this either by adding an ID to the element that the they're click on, or simply by defining a separate onclick handler that then calls a utility method like this:

```
<a onclick={handleOpenTaskClick}/>
```

In the JavaScript, we can then start to handle this and navigate the user.

```
handleOpenTaskClick(event) {
   navigateUser('Open');
}

navigateUser(status){
    //code to navigate user.
    this[NavigationMixin.Navigate]({
        type: 'comm__namedPage',
        attributes: {
            name: 'TaskList__c'
        },
        state: {
            c__Status: status,
        },
    });
}
```

In your second component, you can then retrieve the state from the URL in your connected callback and apply the filter:

```
@wire(CurrentPageReference)
getStateParameters(currentPageReference) {
   if (currentPageReference) {
       this.StatusFilter = currentPageReference.state?.c__Status;
   }
}
```